# Accessing multiple columns when corresponding to certain rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Right now, I am running this line of code:

```
PIDdf = clean_CSV['PID'].value_counts(normalize = True).nlargest(5).mul(100).round(1).astype(str) + '%'
```

on this dataset

| Proto | Local Address | Foreign Address | State | PID | Process_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TCP | [0.0.0.0:7] | 0.0.0.0:0 | LISTENING | 4112 | tcpsvcs.exe |
| TCP | 0.0.0.0:111 | 0.0.0.0:0 | LISTENING | 4 | Can not obtain ownership information |

and the code returns just this

| PID |  |
| --- | --- |
| 6356 | 11.1% |
| 32744 | 10.4% |
| 9196 | 3.3% |
| 2652 | 3.3% |
| 27468 | 3.3% |

But I would like to see this:

| PID |  | Process_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6356 | 11.1% | sdfasdfa |
| 32744 | 10.4% | adsfasdf |
| 9196 | 3.3% | asdfasd |
| 2652 | 3.3% | asdfsad |
| 27468 | 3.3% | asdfsdaf |

Is there a better of doing this rather than just finding the largest columns of the same process_names and appending it?

Comment: you are saying "finding the largest columns", but I think you meant "finding the largest **rows**", correct?

Comment: What values should be in the column `Process_name` in the result? Where do they come from?

Comment: is it guaranteed that same `PID` will have the same `Process_name`?

Comment: @VladimirFokow sorry about that, let me edit this right now. And it can be any value, I just want the corresponding column for that PID to be there as well. The PID is guaranteed to have that Process_name.

Comment: so does the existing answer solve your problem?

Comment: It does but I am trying to understand how the code he wrote works. Does it get the value count for both PID and Process_name or does it just get the PID and the corresponding Process_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC , here is one way :

```
PIDdf = df[['PID','Process_name']].value_counts(normalize = True).nlargest(5).mul(100).round(1).astype(str) + '%'
```

another way :

```
PIDdf = df.groupby(['PID','Process_name'])['PID'].count().divide(df.shape[0]).nlargest(5).mul(100).round(1).astype(str) + '%'
```

output:

```
>>>
PID   Process_name                        
4     Can not obtain ownership information    50.0%
4112  tcpsvcs.exe                             50.0%
```

Comment: Does it get the value count for both PID and Process_name or does it just get the PID and the corresponding Process_name within the same row?

Comment: @ZarifRahman yes for both , but if pid always has the same process_name , it really doesn't matter. and if a pid can have multiple different process_name , what you want it not correct.